# Trying to line up the bottom text in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the text in this `<div>` to line up. Either get the text to be `vertical-align: middle` or along the bottom. Right now, the 'Due by:' text ends up lined up with the top of the 'Finish Task' button.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 25px;vertical-align: middle;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
        Due by: 02/12/2016
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; 
            float: right; margin-right: -10px; vertical-align: middle;">
        <div class="eed-button-grn button-space submit_link">Finish Task</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddler Link](https://jsfiddle.net/se7un114/)

Comment: Just to be clear - you're trying to align the text with the green button on the right, aren't you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it ends up at the top. When I click your jfiddle, Due by: is at the bottom left of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution, add `line-height` property:

```
<div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle; line-height:28px;">
  Due by: 02/12/2016
</div>
```

Not sure if it is the optimal/best way to do it though.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/654o37dL/)

Answer (score 1):

Vertically align with flexbox. It's the easiest way.

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; background: red; height: 250px;">
     <div class="cnt">
          <div style="display: inline-block;">
               Due by: 02/12/2016
          </div>
          <div style="display: inline-block; float: right; margin-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;">
               <div class="eed-button-grn button-space submit_link">Finish Task</div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try applying the following styles to the text element:

```
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```